# Magento 2: use a chooser widget as a system configuration field

Tags: magento2, configuration, magento-2.0, widgets, system.xml

Is there an easy way to use the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Widget\Chooser` in my `system.xml` file for a field ?

The idea is to be able to pick a category from the chooser widget to store its id as a configuration field.

I don't want to use a simple text input as people will have to find the category id by themselves.

Comment: Or even a grid view with checkbox (like grid-serializer) can be life saver in such cases.

Comment: Are you able to manage this?

Comment: @MagePsycho nope still haven't found a way

Comment: Renga I tried to use your solution but checkboxes are not coming. only tree is visible. I am using magento 2.3

Answer (score 5):

To Creating A Multiple Category Chooser in Backend:

In your Widget.xml:

```
<parameter name="multi_category_chooser" xsi:type="block" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="10">
            <label translate="true">Select Categories</label>
            <block class="[Vendor]\[Modul]\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Widget\[Chooser]" />
        </parameter>
```

Create File : [Vendor][Modul]\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Widget[Chooser]

```
    <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Widget;

class Chooser extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template {

    protected $_elementFactory;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory, array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_elementFactory = $elementFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare chooser element HTML
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element Form Element
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
     */
    public function prepareElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $htmlId = $element->getId();
        $data = $element->getData();

        $data['after_element_js'] = $this->_afterElementJs($element);
        $data['after_element_html'] = $this->_afterElementHtml($element);
        $data['readonly'] = 'readonly';
        $htmlItem = $this->_elementFactory->create('text', ['data' => $data]);
        $htmlItem
                ->setId("{$htmlId}")
                ->setForm($element->getForm())
                ->addClass('required-entry')
                ->addClass('entities');
        $return = <<<HTML
                <div id="{$htmlId}-container" class="chooser_container">{$htmlItem->getElementHtml()}</div>
HTML;
        $element->setData('after_element_html', $return);
        return $element;
    }

    protected function _afterElementHtml($element)
    {
        $htmlId = $element->getId();
        $return = <<<HTML
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="MultiCategoryChooser.displayChooser('{$htmlId}-container')" class="widget-option-chooser" title="{__('Open Chooser')}">
                <img src="{$this->getViewFileUrl('images/rule_chooser_trigger.gif')}" alt="{__('Open Chooser')}" />
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="MultiCategoryChooser.hideChooser('{$htmlId}-container')" title="{__('Apply')}">
                <img src="{$this->getViewFileUrl('images/rule_component_apply.gif')}" alt="{__('Apply')}">
            </a>
            <div class="chooser"></div>
HTML;
        return $return;
    }

    protected function _afterElementJs($element)
    {
        $chooserUrl = $this->getUrl('adminhtml/widget_instance/categories', []);
        $htmlId     = $element->getId();
        $return = <<<HTML
            <script>
                    require([
                    'jquery',
                    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
                    "prototype"
                ], function (jQuery, alert) {
                    var MultiCategoryChooser = {
                        displayChooser : function(chooser) {
                                chooser  = $(chooser).down('div.chooser');
                                entities = chooser.up('div.chooser_container').down('input[type="text"].entities').value;
                                postParameters = {selected: entities};
                                url = '{$chooserUrl}';

                                if (chooser && url) {
                                if (chooser.innerHTML == '') {
                                        new Ajax.Request(url, {
                                        method  : 'post',
                                        parameters : postParameters,
                                        onSuccess  : function(transport) {
                                                try {
                                                if (transport.responseText) {
                                                    Element.insert(chooser, transport.responseText);
                                                    chooser.removeClassName('no-display');
                                                    chooser.show();
                                                }
                                                } catch (e) {
                                                alert({
                                                   content: 'Error occurs during loading chooser.'
                                                });
                                                }
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    chooser.removeClassName('no-display');
                                    chooser.show();
                                }
                                }
                       },
                        hideChooser : function(chooser) {
                                chooser = $(chooser).down('div.chooser');
                                if (chooser) {
                                chooser.addClassName('no-display');
                                chooser.hide();
                                }
                        },
                        checkCategory : function(event) {
                                node    = event.memo.node;
                                container = event.target.up('div.chooser_container');
                                value   = container.down('input[type="text"].entities').value.strip();
                                if (node.attributes.checked) {
                                if (value) ids = value.split(',');
                                else ids = [];
                                if (-1 == ids.indexOf(node.id)) {
                                    ids.push(node.id);
                                    container.down('input[type="text"].entities').value = ids.join(',');
                                }
                                } else {
                                ids = value.split(',');
                                while (-1 != ids.indexOf(node.id)) {
                                    ids.splice(ids.indexOf(node.id), 1);
                                    container.down('input[type="text"].entities').value = ids.join(',');
                                }
                                }
                        }
                      }
                    window.MultiCategoryChooser = MultiCategoryChooser;
                    jQuery(function() {
                        var container = $('{$htmlId}-container');
                        if (container) {
                            container.up(0).down('.control-value').hide();
                        }

                        Event.observe(document, 'node:changed', function(event){
                            MultiCategoryChooser.checkCategory(event);
                        });
                        Event.observe(document, 'category:beforeLoad', function(event) {
                                container = event.target.up('div.chooser_container');
                                value   = container.down('input[type="text"].entities').value.strip();
                            event.memo.treeLoader.baseParams.selected = value;
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
HTML;
        return $return;
    }
}
```

This is the Multi Category Chooser.
[image]

Comment: I need same but your code is not working

Comment: Ok, where you struggled  Give more info otherwise I'm helpless. Because it's successfully working for me.

Comment: Thanks for reply I want  to add category chooser in my custom module  can you please tell me the code where I ad and get proper category chooser

Comment: Can I use this in custom admin form without ui component?

Comment: I am getting this error: doesn't extend \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement