# Category chooser widget as system configuration field

Tags: magento-1.9

I need a category chooser field in my modules config tab. I already saw a lot of widget tutorials, including [this](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration), from Alan Storm, and it is very helpful. But i want something more specific.

**I need a widget like the one that is present in Promotions -> Cart Rules**

[image]

When you open this chooser, the categories are listed and you can choose them with the checkbox. Then, the **ID** of the selected categories go to the field **Category**. That's what i want.

- I would like to know where can i find the code about this widget in
  magento or
- If someone have a solution that do something like the print above.

I already saw some questions about this, like [this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/116073/31366), but my solution must be for magento 1.9.x.