# Add category input to widget.xml

Tags: magento2, admin, widget

[image]

How to add this to my custom widget at backend?

Comment: custom widget?? Could you please explain?

Comment: i create a custom widget call bestselling product, now i want a multi category input field like this

Comment: Is it a widget you are creating or the module?

Comment: my module of course

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a category chooser for the Magento Admin Panel:

Backend configurations:

```
<field id="multi_category_chooser" translate="label" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
<label>Categories</label>
<frontend_model>[Vendor]\[Modul]\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Widget\[Chooser]</frontend_model>
```

Or

```
$fieldset->addField(
'multi_category_chooser',
'[Vendor]\[Modul]\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Widget\[Chooser]',
[
    'name' => 'multi_category_chooser',
    'label' => __('Categories'),
    'title' => __('Categories'),
    'required' => true
]
```

);

To Be Continued in below url

[Multiple Category Chooser](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116073/magento-2-use-a-chooser-widget-as-a-system-configuration-field/220045#220045)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$categories = $fieldsetData->addField(
'categories',
'Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Category',
[
'name' => 'categories',
'label' => __('Categories'),
'required' => TRUE,
]
);
```

and adding < css src="Magento_Catalog::catalog/category-selector.css"/ > to your layout.

I haven't checked it but it worked for others.Please see [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/971).

Hope it helps you. If it does, please accept the answer and vote it up, so that it could help others too.

Regards

Comment: i have checked this but really don't know how to do it, where should i put the code in?

Comment: You should add it to the admin form, basically "Package_name/Module_name/Adminhtml/Module_name/Edit/Tab/filename.php"

Comment: this not work at all

Comment: What variable you used? In above example its $fieldsetData but in your case it could be different? Did you find the file where you need to add that?