# Multiselect category dropdown on admin form

Tags: admin, category, magento-2.2.5, category-tree

I have created **custom CRUD** on **new database table**. I just wanted to save comma separated categories in a field.

I have this code for multiselect categories:

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'categories',
    'multiselect',
    [
        'label' => __('Categories'),
        'title' => __('Categories'),
        'name' => 'categories',
        'values' => \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Products\Grid::getCategories(),
        'note' => __('Could be multiple'),
        'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
    ]
);
```

I have created `getCategories` function in **Grid.php**.

Can anyone suggested how to populate categories in tree form and return categories array

Comment: I have done with Default Category Chooser. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116073/magento-2-use-a-chooser-widget-as-a-system-configuration-field/220045#220045. Please look at this maybe it will helps you.

Comment: @Renga thanks for your input. I need this on admin form, how would I do that from your code?

Comment: try with setRenderer() method.

Comment: $field = $fieldset->addField(
                'store_id',
                'select',
                [
                    'label' => __('Store'),
                    'title' => __('Store'),
                    'values' => '1',
                    'name' => 'store_id',
                    'required' => true
                ]
);
$renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
'Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Element'
);
$field->setRenderer($renderer);

Comment: I will try your code. I suggest you add these in answer

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many tries, I have figured out the solution for my own question.

I used this code to make multiselect (as mentioned in my question):

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'categories',
    'multiselect',
    [
        'label' => __('Categories'),
        'title' => __('Categories'),
        'name' => 'categories',
        'values' => \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Products\Grid::getCategories(),
        'note' => __('Could be multiple'),
        'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
    ]
);
```

In Grid.php file I have created two functions
one is to create simple array for multi select values:

```
static public function getCategories()
{
    $data_array = array();
    foreach (\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Productsgrid\Grid::getCategoryTree() as $k => $v) {
        $data_array[] = array('value' => $k, 'label' => $v);
    }
    return ($data_array);

}
```

And the 2nd one is a recursive function to generate category tree

```
static public function getCategoryTree($categories = "", $data_array = array())
{
    if(empty($categories)) {
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $categoryFactory = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
        $categories = $categoryFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')//or you can just add some attributes
            ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)//2 is actually the first level
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//if you want only active categories
            ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC');
    }

    foreach($categories as $k=>$category){
        $level = $category->getLevel();
        $data_array[$category->getId()] = str_repeat("*",$level)." ".$category->getName();
        $childCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        if(count($childCategories) > 0){
            $data_array = \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Productsgrid\Grid::getCategoryTree($childCategories, $data_array);
        }
    }
    if(count($data_array) == 0){
        return $data_array;
    }
    return ($data_array);
}
```

My final array `$data_array` contains the **IDs** in array key and **Category title** in values.

Comment: How do you set the previously-selected Categories as selected when the AdminHTML page is reloaded?

Comment: Magento auto-selects the category which is saved before, I really didn't had to do anything for this